# Fonts supporting Hawaiian Characters?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

For a map of Hawaiʻi, I am looking for serif and a non-serif font **supporting Hawaiian characters**.

The fonts should go well with a modern map. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a list of Win7 and MacOS fonts listed with supported ‘Okina and Kahakō and other special characters:

MacOS
- https://www.scribd.com/document/46345021/Apple-Fonts-With-Okina-and-Kahak%C5%8D

Windows 7
- https://www.scribd.com/document/49746063/Win-7-Hawaiian-Support